# Jquery/js specific time with minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i'm making a simple jquery function that keep track of what time it is and either displays if the shop is open or closed by changing the display property of my div.

But i need to incorporate minutes as well, because the shop open for example at 7:30. How do I use minutes with hours to make it work?

I thought it would like something like: && hour + minutes <= 11.30 && hour <= 18.00) ? But this doesn't work. Any help is appreciated

```
 var now = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Monday";
    weekday[1] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[2] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[3] = "Thursday";
    weekday[4] = "Friday";
    weekday[5] = "Saturday";
    weekday[6] = "Sunday";

    var checkTime = function() {
      var dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
      var hour = now.getHours();
      var minutes = now.getMinutes();



      if (( dayOfWeek == 6)) {
        $('.opening-js').css('display', 'none');
        $('.availability-status-closed').css('display', 'block');
      } 

    else if ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3) && hour <= 11 && hour <= 18.00) {
         $('.opening-js').css('display', 'none');
         $('.availability-status-closed').css('display', 'block');
      } 

     else if ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3) && hour >= 11 && hour <= 18.00) {
         $('.opening-js').css('display', 'block');
         $('.availability-status-closed').css('display', 'none');
      } 

      else {
        if ((dayOfWeek == 5) && hour >= 10.00 && hour <= 16.00) {
          $('.availability-status-open').css("display", "block");
          $('.availability-status-closed').css("display", "none");
        }
      }
    };
    setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
    checkTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `hour` and `minutes` in your code are integers

```
var hour = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
```

So you need to use both variables

```
if((hour == 7 && minutes>=30) || hour>7){
   // it is 7:30 or later.
}
```

or, you can reduce it to the lowest common denominator... `totalMinutes`

```
var totalMinutes = (now.getHours()*60) + now.getMinutes();
var sevenThirty = (7*60)+30;
if(totalMinutes >= sevenThirty){
    // it is 7:30 or later
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding the second code piece like this : && hour <= 11 && minutes <= 30 && hour > 18 but it's not working

Comment: @TobiasHeide the hour cannot be *both* before 11 AND after 18. Hence the use of brackets and OR in my code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the time as a string, try to convert your hours and minutes in a single string at first.

For example

```
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours().toString().length > 1 ? now.getHours() : "0" + now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes().toString().length > 1 ? now.getMinutes() : "0" + now.getMinutes();

var time = hours + "." + minutes;

console.log(time);
```

The other option it to compare just `Date` objects.

```
var time1130 = new Date();
time1130.setHours(11);
time1130.setMinutes(30);

console.log(now > time1130);
```

Or compare integers (that probably the easiest way), as it mentioned in Jamiec answer

Comment: You'll need to zeropad the hour too to make this work.